# XCode 4.0 internal logic error. will updating to 4.0.2 help?

Tags: xcode4

I'm running XCode 4.0 I'm getting that error:

```
Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state. Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

and also when i click on the show details button it gives me this:

ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-215/Framework/Classes/PlugInArchitectu re/DVTPlugInManager.m:215
Details: (extensionPoint) should not be nil.
Object: <DVTPlugInManager: 0x2000a3c20>
Method: -_extensionsForExtensionPoint:matchingPredicate:
Thread: <NSThread: 0x200020600>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace: .............
```

I get this error if I try create a new file or modify any preferences, If I do just about anything. Could it be the actual project, it doesnt seem to happen with other projects.
It ran fine till I tried to add the Facebook IOS SDK to my project and then XCode "fell over". I have since removed the facebook SDK and still it happens I also opened a previous version of my app and still the same error.

I've tried clearing all the cache and still nothing works, is it worth downloading XCode 4.0.2 to resolve this or are there maybe other options. I'm in South Africa and 4 Gigs of data isn't for free.

I guess updating XCode to the latest version is always a good thing but is it that much better than 4.0? If there are other options to fix or find the problem, I would prefer it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, although upgrading to 4.0.2 didn't do the trick, what I had to do is create a new project, and transfer all my files and change all my build settings after this it ran smoothly ever since. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything I've seen under this heading to stop xcode from crashing when debugging a simple C  project.  I even completely reinstalled Xcode4.

Finally tried this and it stopped the problem.

cd to the xcodeproj directory and:

```
rm -rf project.xcworkspace xcuserdata
```

I believe what I did that led up to the long series of crashes is set a watchpoint on a variable. I'm uncertain, but it was nearly the last significant thing I did before Xcode started puking on my shoes irrevocably.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a project stored in subversion.
I removed project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata from the xcodeproj directory and I also removed all .svn directories.
Building worked fine after.